# Lebesgue integral with the absolute value on ball

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I would like to calculate the integral

> $$\intop_{B(x,r)}\left(1+\left|y\right|\right)^{\alpha}\,dy,$$
>    where $x\in\mathbb{\mathbb{R}^{n}}$, $\alpha>0$ and $B(x,r)=\left\{ y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\:|x-y|<r\right\}$.

I tried substitution $y=\frac{z-x}{r}$ or using Tonelli theorem and considering the sphere, but I always had a problem with the absolute value. Do you have any other ideas or tips?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By using translation invariance of Lebesgue's measure and changing to polar coordinates you get

$$\int_{B(x,r)}\left(1+\left|y\right|\right)^{\alpha}\,dy= n V_n\int_0^r\left(1+s\right)^\alpha s^{n-1}\,ds,$$

where $V_n$ denotes the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit ball.

Comment: Are you sure that the result does not depend on the modulus of x?